# Drag marker on map

Tags: android

How can I drag a marker on the map?
How to handle it in onTouchEvent()?

I had written one code that actually drags. But it feels like the map is moving instead of the marker. That code is written below:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {

   /*Action to be taken on ACTION_UP(value=1) and ACTION_DOWN(value=0)*/
   if(event.getAction() == 0 || event.getAction() == 1){
      mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
   }  

   /*Action to be taken on ACTION_MOVE(value=2)*/
   if(event.getAction() == 2){  
      for(int i = 0; i < mOverlays.size() ; i++){
        mOverlays.remove(i);
      }

      GeoPoint point = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(),(int) 
                  event.getY());

      OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, "", "");
      addOverlay(overlayItem); 
      mapView.getController().setCenter(point);
   }

   return true;
}
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Of course the map is moving. You are telling the map to move via `setCenter()`.

[Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkTouch/) showing drag and drop of `OverlayItems`.